# R-2.15 on AIX5.3 - rl_readline_name error and configure

Tags: r, sed, configure, aix

I am trying to install R package on AIX5.3. I've two queries regarding it:

1. I followed [Fan Long's](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-admin/R-admin_97.html) steps. I installed the GNU utilities: libiconv and gettext also. However, on running

> ./configure --with-libpth-prefix=/home/jayant/utils --disable-nls --without-libintl-prefiX --with-included-gettext=home/jayant/utils --with-blas="-llapack -lessl -lblas" --prefix=home/jayant/R-2.15.3

I get the following error:

> "sys-std.c", line 893.13: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier rl_readline_name.

1. Native 'sed' on aix does not support '-e' option. I installed sed from GNU utilities. In the configure script, how should I force it to take my sed instead of the native one. I tried

> export sed=/home/jayant/sed-4.2/bin/sed.

but it does'nt work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the desired `sed` gets *picked* up.  Say:

```
PATH=/home/jayant/sed-4.2/bin:${PATH} ./configure ...
```

Or if you want to add it to the `PATH`, say:

```
PATH=/home/jayant/sed-4.2/bin:${PATH}; export PATH
```

(Add it to your `${HOME}/.bashrc` if you so desire.)